# How to validate privateKey bit length for BouncyCastle decryption?

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, private-key

I'm currently trying to implement a decrypt method on c# for a DecodeService I have. In this DecodeService I need to have a method that can receive an input string (the cipher data) and a private key (that is generated in another service).

The generated key that I'm getting looks something like this:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I've tried implementing this decrypt method the following way:

```
    public string RSADecryptString(string inputString, string privateKey)
    {
        BCEngine bcEngine = new BCEngine(new AesEngine(), _encoding);
        bcEngine.SetPadding(_padding);
        return bcEngine.Decrypt(inputString, privateKey);
    }
```

While looking for a BouncyCastle decrypt implementation I found the one above and also the privateKey I'm receiving is generated by BouncyCastle.

But I'm getting the error that my private key is not 128/192/256 bits. And I don't know how to validate it. Or maybe it is because the private key I'm receiving is in the wrong format for my decrypt method?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: AES != RSA, therefore AesEngine will not help you decrypt an RSA-encrypted value.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thanks for the aclaration.